# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: 'undefined' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "mgmt"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Im getting an error when I try updating, viewing and deleting a user. Im not sure how its happening but im storing the users data in an array from my frontend.

Here is my error.

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: 'undefined' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "mgmt"
```

Here is my User schema for the structure of how the users

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let mgmtSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    email: { type: String, required: true},
    contact: { type: Number, required: true},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('mgmt', mgmtSchema);
```

In my frontend im trying to connect the backend with axios and using the useState hook to store the users data.

```
const initialState = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    contact: ''
}

const AddEdit = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(initialState)
    const { name, email, contact } = data

    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const { id } = useParams()

    useEffect(() => {
        if(id) {
            getExistingUser(id)
        }
    }, [id])

    const getExistingUser = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5500/api/user/${id}`)
        if(res.status === 200) {
           setData({...res.data})
        }
    }

    const updateContact = async (data) => {
        const res = await axios.put(`http://localhost:5500/api/user/${id}`, data)
        if(res.status === 200) {
            toast.success(res.data)
        }
    }

    const addContact = async (data) => {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5500/api/user', data)
        if(res.status === 200) {
            toast.success(res.data)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `const { id } = useParams()`  Did you try logging `id` ?

Comment: Remove passing id in params from `getExistingUser(id)` when you're not using `id` in that function from params?

Comment: Error clearly says that the `_id` you passed to query is undefined. Debug  your flow. Check if you are sending `id` from frontend, if yes check server and see if you are receiving the `id` in params.

Comment: Ive logged the id from the useParams() and in the console it reads 'undefined}'

Comment: In the frontend and backend i console logged both params and they both read undefined. In thunderClient, where i checked my routes they run perfectly fine. When i update my user in thunderClient here are my results.  {
  "user": {
    "_id": "620d54ba17476d1d21cced76",
    "name": "frankie mueler",
    "email": "franki@gmail.com",
    "contact": 1234567890,
    "date": "2022-02-16T19:47:06.256Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
}

Comment: In my schema, should I manually create an Id to be able to access the id in the frontend and backend?